# Transformation law of a matrix of scalars

Tags: homework-and-exercises, field-theory, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance

If I have a theory with a $2 \times 2$ matrix $\Phi$ of scalars that transforms under a gauge group $SU(2)_L \times SU(2)_R$ as $\Phi \rightarrow U_L \Phi U_R^{\dagger}$, how does $\Phi$ transform under an $SU(2)_{L+R}$ group generated by the sum of the generators of $SU(2)_L$ and $SU(2)_R$?

Comment: This is a straightforward calculation, and it would be much better for you if you arrived at the answer yourself. Have you tried doing the calculation? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: @Prof.Legolasov I don't really know how to tackle the problem. Does it have something to do with the singlet and the triplet?

Answer (score 0):

This is explained in most good QFT textbooks; in simplified normalization,
$$
\Phi \rightarrow U_L \Phi U_R^{\dagger}= e^{i\vec \theta_L \cdot \vec \tau}  \Phi e^{-i\vec \theta_R \cdot \vec \tau}.
$$
That is, the same-looking *SU(2)* generators are used for the left and the right multiplication by different angles.
This is reflected in the cartesian product $SU(2)_L \times SU(2)_R$ which signifies the L and right generators commute,
$$[\tau^i_L,\tau^j_R]=0. $$
This means that the three diagonal combinations $\tau^i_L +\tau^i_R $ close into a subalgebra of the full 6 generator algebra, which generates the diagonal ("vector") subgroup $SU(2)_{L+R}$. But then the *angles* of these rotations must be the same for both L and R, $\theta_L=\theta_R\equiv \theta $, like synchronized parity-reflected swimming,
$$
 \Phi \rightarrow e^{i\vec \theta \cdot \vec \tau}  \Phi e^{-i\vec \theta \cdot \vec \tau}.
$$
It is then manifest that $\Phi$ is transforming in the *adjoint* (triplet) rep of this diagonal *SU(2)*.

This is the gist of Gell-Mann's [current algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_algebra).